# glob only pulling array if I use wildcard

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `glob()` to find images in my folder that match a pattern. There are too many images to manually search through, so `glob()` seems like a good approach.

I don't seem to be able to get glob to work, however.

I have 5 images with the following patter: `diamond_z_classic_397-106` but when I use glob as such:

`print_r(glob("diamond_z_classic_397-106.*"));` then this is what is returned `array()` . When I do this: `pring_r(glob("*.*"));` then it pulls everything from the directory included the 5 matches.

I've scanned SO as well as  http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp to figure out what I'm missing.

What could be causing this, or what am I missing.

Also, is it possible to use a variable like this: `glob("$pattern.*");` ?

Thanks

**Update**
Here are the 5 exact names that should match the pattern:
`diamond_z_classic_397-106-100-80-100-c-rd-255-255-255.jpg`

`diamond_z_classic_397-106-100-80-100-c.jpg`

`diamond_z_classic_397-106-120-90-100-c.jpg`

`diamond_z_classic_397-106-300-300-100-wm-center_middle-0-ColorCountryAussies-255-255-255-35.jpg`

`diamond_z_classic_397-106-800-800-100-wm-center_middle-0-ColorCountryAussies-255-255-255-35.jpg`

Comment: empty array means there  where simply no matches for that pattern

Comment: That pattern does show up when I use the wildcard `*` though

Comment: either you or php is wrong, im betting on ...

Comment: I'm using the php in the code above. The only thing I'm changing in them is one I put the pattern and in the other I'm using the wildcard.

Comment: case sensitive? special characters? spaces - all could be an issue

Comment: Here is one of the exact names: `diamond_z_classic_397-106-100-80-100-c-rd-255-255-255.jpg` I only get it when I use the wildcard, but when I put this part of the pattern `diamond_z_classic_397-106` I get an empty array @PaulCrovella

Comment: missing wild card there `diamond_z_classic_397-106*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.` from your pattern, i.e. `glob("diamond_z_classic_397-106*")`.

With [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) `*` alone matches zero or more of any character. You're attempting to match a literal `.` that doesn't exist at that place in your file names.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Do you know of a way to take the array and move those files to another directory?

Comment: @MDavid if you  only want glob to then move the files it can all be done a lot easier(and faster)  `exec('mv diamond_z_classic_397-106*  /destination/');`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have truncated your filename with "." and its taking it literally.
Try something like

```
print_r(glob("diamond_z_classic_397-106*"));
```

Also yes, you can define a string beforehand and pass it as an argument.

```
$pattern = "xyz*"
print_r(glob($pattern));
```